# Choose only the Records with the most Recent Date

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

My report has {?Start Date} and {?End Date} paramters and groups by items.  Every column displays a sum of the data values between the two dates (Quantity Sold, Quantity Transferred, etc). That's working fine.  However, I have one column where it has to display the most recent inventory levels between the parameters.

For example, if I do February 1-28, 2017, the other columns will take the sum of data between these dates.  However for the inventory column, I need it to display the inventory level when it was last updated between the two parameters.

So some items will have had its inventory last updated on Feb 28, some other others would have been last updated on Feb 27, Feb 26 or some other random day. 
The inventory levels for each item is updated many times throughout the month.

How do I write a formula so it will display the inventory levels from only the most recent date between the two parameters? I use `table.dateupdated` and `table.invquantity`.

Comment: Try to use sql expression fields

Comment: can you show us some rows of your data (as they appear in database) as a sample? Also can you display the sql command you send to the report?